# given the length of event $x$, in $90$ occurrences how many times will length length $x$ be greater than $3$?

Tags: probability, statistics

the length of event $x$ has approximately an exponential distribution with a mean of 90 minutes. if event $x$ occurs $90$ times, how many times will the event last longer than $3$ hours?

My work so far:

here for exponential distribution parameter $β = 90$

$P$ (event occur after 3 hours (180 minutes)):

$$P(X>180)=1-P(X<180)=1-(1-\exp(-180/90))= 0.1353$$

therefore the number of events that last longer than $3$ hours

$$=np=90*0.1353= 12.177 \sim 12$$

Comment: Solution is correct!

Comment: Yes, in R `p = 1 - pexp(3, 2/3); 90*p` returns $12.18018.$